Aproximation Algorithim for Max Subset Problem
I'm looking for an approximation approach to what I am assuming is an NP hard problem. Given a list of sets F = {S1,...,Sm) that contain at most n elements from (0,...,n-1): what is the largest subset S⊆(0,...,n-1) such that maximizes |S| * number of sets where S⊆Sm.
I implemented a brute force version of this problem to test other exact algorithms but none seem to fast enough to solve large values of n. Perhaps this problem exists under different conditions or keywords so maybe someone could point me in the right direction in terms of implementing a fast exact solution or an approximation.

By what criteria will you judge the merit of any proposed heuristic? For example, do you wish to limit consideration to heuristics for which a bound can be computed on the difference between the value produced by the heuristic and the (unknown) optimal value?

What are the expected bounds for "n" and "m"?
